# Can't Get Updated Value From Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox, save

I have just began to develop web applications at visual studio, with c# and asp.net. In one of my pages, I have set the textbox's text value to something. The user can change the text and save it. Clicking save button, i got to get the new text value from the textbox but i always get the first text set. I would be so glad if you help me.

Comment: please show some source code...

Comment: Post your code. This sounds like it's an issue with checking for `IsPostBack`.

Comment: Mert mark the correct answer [DOK's answer], this will encourage people giving answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Often this can be caused by setting the textbox value in `Page_Load` without wrapping that in `!IsPostBack`. When a page is submitted, the `Page_Load` event runs before the button click event. So, the textbox value gets repopulated with its original value before the click event looks at that value.

If this is the situation, then you can wrap the code that assigns the value to the textbox in an if block like this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   // set the textbox value
}
```

Comment: Every single one of us has stubbed our toe on this one, Mert. Welcome to the club!

Comment: @MertKaratas - please mark the answer as answered below the voting number so that other users who experience the same problem identify the solution easily. Thanks and welcome !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your text box isn't properly tied to your view model. Some sample code could help verify though.